# ViewPager in inner fragment, not showing up, not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

Im using an ActionBar, which loads different Fragments. This is done within a FragmentActivity class. One of the Fragent should have a ViewPager holding different Fragments.
I dont get any error anymore now, but the ViewPager and the PagerTitleStrip and all the Fragents inside the ViewPager are not shown up at all. The other Fragments from the ActionBar working properly. Im using all classes from the Support-Package.
I rdid read a lot of posts here, but I couldnt find it out yet.

In my ActivityClass derived from FragmentAcivity, I use the Listener:

SettingsActiviy.java

```
protected class SettingsTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public SettingsTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        Log.e("SettingsTabListener","Contructor Fragment is " + fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction xaction=fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        // Dont know if we really need that...
        if (fragment instanceof SettingsActivityOverviewFragment) {
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = SettingsActivityOverviewFragment.newInstance(appWidgetId);
            }
        }
        xaction.replace(R.id.FragmentPlaceholder, (Fragment)fragment);
        xaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction xaction=fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        xaction.remove(fragment);
        xaction.commit();
    }
```

SettingsActivityOverviewFragment.java

```
public class SettingsActivityOverviewFragment extends Fragment {
private static final Field sChildFragmentManagerField;
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

public static final SettingsActivityOverviewFragment newInstance(int appWidgetId){
    SettingsActivityOverviewFragment f = new SettingsActivityOverviewFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    bdl.putInt("appWidgetId", appWidgetId);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}
```

/* this is a fix caused by googles nullpointer, until detach-method */

```
static {
    Field f = null;
    try {
        f = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        f.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    }
    sChildFragmentManagerField = f;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    if (sChildFragmentManagerField != null) {
        try {
            sChildFragmentManagerField.set(this, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

/* end of fix */

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_frag_overview, container, false);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.overview_pager);
    Log.e("SettingsActivityOverviewFragment","viewPager content is " + viewPager + ", " + viewPager.getHeight());

    pagerAdapter = buildAdapter();
    new SetAdapterTask().execute();

    return(result);
  }

  private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new SettingsOverviewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
  }

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, android.content.Intent data) {

  }

  private class SetAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            if(pagerAdapter != null) viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

SettingsOverviewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class SettingsOverviewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context ctxt=null;

  public SettingsOverviewPagerAdapter(Context ctxt, FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
    this.ctxt=ctxt;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      Log.i("SettingsOverviewPagerAdapter","getCount returns 10");
    return(10);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return(EditorFragment.newInstance(position));
  }

  @Override
  public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return(EditorFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position));
  }
}
```

EditorFragment.java

```
public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";

static EditorFragment newInstance(int position) {
    EditorFragment frag = new EditorFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return (frag);
}

static String getTitle(Context ctxt, int position) {
    return (String.format("ctest", position + 1));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);
    EditText editor = (EditText) result.findViewById(R.id.editor);
    int position = getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);

    editor.setHint(getTitle(getActivity(), position));

    return (result);
}
 }
```

SettingsFragOverview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/overview_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:background="#33b5e5"
      android:textColor="#fff"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

EditorFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/editor"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:inputType="textMultiLine"
   android:gravity="left|top"
/>
```

Comment: Is your viewpager wrapped in a scrollview?

Comment: not the viewpager directly is wrapped in a scrollview, but the parent Fragment is wrapped inside a scrollview yes

Comment: ohhh...i saw when I removed the Scrollview...it's shown up...thanks for that tipp!

Answer (score 7):

This typically occurs when:

- Using an inner fragment as parent of ViewPager
- Parent container has a scrollview in it.

Comment: ScrollView caused the fragment to not show up.
Thanks for the answer. However do you know why?